# Get if any RadioButton in a Groupbox was checked

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button, groupbox

I have a Windows Forms application, where I have several radio buttons stored in a `GroupBox`. I need to enable a different `GroupBox` based on the selected radio button.

`groubBox.Enter` doesn't seem to be the `EventHandler` I was looking for. Is there any way to do it my way or do I have to create a handler for each `radiobutton.CheckedChanged`?

**Edit**

The workflow of the application is:

A file gets selected → The `GroupBox` gets enabled → A `Panel`/`ComboBox`, `TextBox` gets enabled depending on the selected `RadioButton`

Comment: You can create one handler which all the radiobuttons use.You must of course differentiate between the different radiobuttons in this handler. Will that help you in any way?

Comment: To check if there is any checked radio button, the most simple option is using a linq query. But for your main requirement to enable or disable groupboxes based on checked radio button, the best solution is using data-binding.

Comment: Also please do't post the solution as a part of question. It will be confusing for future readers. You can accept the best solution, you can upvote useful answers and also you an post your own answer if you think you have a better answer. Also to link to another useful answer, just use a comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `gbRadioButtons` be the name of the GroupBox, Then you can iterate though each radioButton in that particular Groupbox and check whether it is selected or not by using the following code(include this code where you want to check):

```
bool isAnyRadioButtonChecked = false;
foreach (RadioButton rdo in gbRadioButtons.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>())
{
    if (rdo.Checked)
    {
        isAnyRadioButtonChecked=true;
        break;
    }
}
if (isAnyRadioButtonChecked)
{ 
  // Code here one button is checked
}
else
{
  // Print message no button is selected 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create `CheckedChanged` event handler, one for all radiobuttons
Set `RadioButton.Tag` to reference the `GroupBox` it respondent for

For example in the constructor

```
public YourForm()
{
    radioButton1.Tag = groupBox1;
    radioButton2.Tag = groupBox2;
    radioButton3.Tag = groupBox3;

    radioButton1.CheckedChanged += radioButtons_CheckedChanged;
    radioButton2.CheckedChanged += radioButtons_CheckedChanged;
    radioButton3.CheckedChanged += radioButtons_CheckedChanged;
}

void radioButtons_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton button = sender as RadioButton;
    if (button == null) return;

    GroupBox box = button.Tag as GroupBox
    if (box == null) return;

    box.Enabled = button.Checked;
}
```

Enabling `GroupBox` will enable all child controls in it