# How to change default radio button checked in c#

Tags: c#, radio-button

How to check radio button default
For example, if I have 5 radio buttons in the group, I want to check the default 1st radio button.
I need a code for updating it, like when the project is running, and I click the 2nd radio button, and the update button default should change to the 2nd radio button.

Comment: You don't need any code if you have the Radio buttons grouped in the same container! So what are you talking about? Please clarify.

Comment: Why don't you use JavaScript for this task?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Winforms

1. Add Settings to you project (Set `int` value)
2. Add the Code will save the current radio checked  **Add in all radios**

   ```
    Properties.Settings.Default.currentRadio = 1;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
   ```
3. In the form initializing set the current checked Radio

   ```
    if (Properties.Settings.Default.currentRadio == 1)
    {
        radioButton1.Checked = true;
    }
    else if(Properties.Settings.Default.currentRadio == 2)
    {
        radioButton2.Checked = true;
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

1. Select all RadioButtons with Strg
2. Go to Events and double click CheckedChanged
3. Then just check whether the button is checked or not

```cs
private void radioButton3_CheckedChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (radioButton1.Checked)
    {
        //Do something
    }
    else if (radioButton2.Checked)
    {
        //Do something
    }
    else if (radioButton3.Checked)
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: I think what this is trying to say is captured here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38911173/get-if-any-radiobutton-in-a-groupbox-was-checked The concept is to create a single event that gets triggered if any of the buttons change by adding the same event to each button's event handler.